# Can I use monospace fonts in a selection list on my web page?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, monospace

I would like to have the entries in a selection list on my web page display in a monospace font.  I tried writing the following HTML.

```
<p style='font-family:"Andale Mono", "Monotype.com", monospace;'>

    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.

    <select multiple="multiple">
      <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
      <option value='2'>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

The result is that the "The quick..." appears monospaced, but the the options are not.  Is 
it possible to make the options appear in a monospaced font, as well?

**Update:** I've discovered that this problem seems to somehow stem from the fact that my select element is within a jQuery-UI tabs div.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with just this in your CSS?

```
option {
  font-family: "Andale Mono", "Monotype.com", monospace;
}
```

Comment: I just copied your suggestion into my CSS and it doesn't seem to work :-(

Comment: I put in my in-line CSS on the page (which already has some working definition).

Comment: I also tried putting the CSS directly on the option and that doesn't seem to work, either.  By the way, I'm testing this with IE7.  The page must work in IE7.

Comment: Actually, when I put your solution in @zooted jsfiddle, it works fine when viewed in Firefox.  This seems to be an issue with IE7.

Answer (score 2):

```
select {
  font-family: "Andale Mono", "Monotype.com", monospace;
}​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LkJfp/

I don't think you *can* do this in IE7 however: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/select-single-optgroup/#ie7-xp

Comment: This works in Firefox, but not in IE7.  I know it's dumb, but I have to target IE7 for my customer.

Comment: I am just...so off. This is a great answer.

Comment: Perhaps it can't be done in IE7. If this is the case, your best option is to create a fake dropdown with `UL` or `DL` and style that.